# List all friends who approved your FB application request

Tags: facebook-graph-api, request, friend

I need to display the names of my friends who approved my application request. I am using this code to send requests to my friends,

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {     
        FB.ui({
            method: 'apprequests',
            message: 'Hey guys check this out'
        });
    } 
});
```

I tried searching answers from other forum but doesn't found any. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your app is proccessing the requests when the recipients accept them, you'll need to save that in your own database, there's no way to subsequently query the API for that information

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have instantiated the facebook class (here, "$Fb"),
and given your id and secret...
"$user" is facebook "user_id" (ie 12345678...) of the user of which we want the list of friends

```
$access_token = $Fb->getAccessToken();
$user_profile = $Fb->api('/me');
// show user image
$txt .= "<p align=\"center\">
            <img src=\"https://graph.facebook.com/".$user."/picture\"></p>";
$FBid = $user_profile['id'];
$FBnick = $user_profile['username'];
$txt .= fb_friends_list($user_profile,$access_token);
echo ($txt);
```

// the above calls the following function to get the friends list:

```
function fb_friends_list($fbup,$access_token)
{
    // display the friends list on 3 columns, with their avatar.
    global $Sess,$Fb;
    $friends = $Fb->api('/me/friends'); // return an array [data][0 to n][name]/[id]
    $siz = sizeof($friends['data']);
    $txt  = "<h3 align=\"center\">Your FRIENDS on FACEBOOK</h3>";
    $txt .= "<table align=\"center\">
                <tr>
                    <td class=\"blu s12 bld\">Friend's<br />Avatar</td>
                    <td class=\"blu s12 bld\">Friend's Name</td>
                    <td width=\"30px\">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class=\"blu s12 bld\">Friend's<br />Avatar</td>
                    <td class=\"blu s12 bld\">Friend's Name</td>
                    <td width=\"30px\">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class=\"blu s12 bld\">Friend's<br />Avatar</td>
                    <td class=\"blu s12 bld\">Friend's Name</td>
                </tr>";
    $col = 0;
    for ($i=0; $i<$siz; $i++)
    {
        $fid = $friends['data'][$i]['id'];
        $src = "http://graph.facebook.com/".$fid."/picture";
        if ($col == 0)
            $txt .= "<tr>";
        $txt .= "<td><img src=\"".$src."\" /></td>";
        $txt .= "<td>".$friends['data'][$i]['name'] . "</td>";
        $txt .= "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"".$fid."\" />";
        $col++;
        if ($col < 3)
            $txt .= "<td width=\"30px\">&nbsp;</td>";
        if ($col == 3)
        {
            $col = 0;
            $txt .= "</tr>";
        }
    }
    if ($col != 0)
        $txt .= "</tr>";
    $txt .= "</table>";
    return($txt);
}
```

Hope it will work for you!